# on click of Product image redirect to external website product details in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to add external links to the product via admin dashboard?

on  click of product image redirect the user to product description page which is on external domain.
screenshot of product 
https://puu.sh/xW4vr/ae64d82537.png

live link screenshot of product description
https://puu.sh/xW4yS/ad3f4b82ba.png

dev live link screenshot of product description
https://puu.sh/xW4y2/42be2acb3f.png

for example : live site URL 
https://www.example.com/product-luggage-rack-wood-20-in-h-holds-300-lb-lrwstd01.html

Redirect to
dev site
https://www.example.dev.com/product-luggage-rack-wood-20-in-h-holds-300-lb-lrwstd01.html

Comment: Did you clear cache, reindex? And what's your website path settings?

Comment: I want to add redirect link to external site, so where to ass in the admin panel dashboard

Comment: I think you want to store the product image via CDN(i.e. external source), right?

Comment: no , on click of the product I want to display product description of another exsternalsite

Comment: e.g   https://www.example.com/ the websites products are shown,when I click on the product the product description should open in external link which has the same clone of the above site   https://www.example.dev.com/product_description_page